# How do I add a three dot vertial ellipsis menu with external links to my app in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, menu

I am trying to add a 3 dot vertical menu to my app and all the buttons will lead to external websites, how do I make this happen in android studio? Does anyone know where I should look on how to do this and to have only external links on the page? I'm not familiar on how to add this so how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [Menu](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/menus):

[image]

You can create and define a menu with the items you want in an XML file under the menu resource folder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Then you can create this menu in your activity and handle the clicks also in the activity:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_name, menu)
    return true
}
```

And when handling clicks, you can go to your external websites

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle item selection
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.new_game -> {
            goToYourWebsite()
            true
        }
        R.id.help -> {
            goToYourSecondWebsite()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

This is a general plan; all the code snippets were taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/menus), you can check the documentation for more ideas.